# How can i Solve this error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php

I am using PHP 8.0 Version but  recently i get this error :
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()

is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Two things: firstly, `mysql_*()` does not exist in PHP8: use PDO or `mysqli_*()` instead. Secondly, don't escape your data: use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_real_escape_string` was **DEPRECATED** in PHP 5.5.0 and **REMOVED** in PHP 7.0.0.¹

PHP recommends using [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

¹ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: i still get the same error